# Sitecore items deletions from a given timestamp

Tags: timestamp, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

I have a requirement for a project where the client asks me to return the deleted items after a given timestamp.

```
/fetch-updates?last-update=[timestamp]
```

I made some research regarding this but couldn't find anything. From what I know if an item is deleted it can't be traced no more, but I might be wrong.

Is there a way to do that?

If not, could you please suggest a way of doing this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default when you delete an item in **Sitecore** it's moved to `Recycle bin`. If the item wasn't removed from the recycle bin you can still find the information when it was deleted.

You can check items in recycle bin using the code:

```cs
Archive archive = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master").Archives["recyclebin"];
List<ArchiveEntry> itemsRemovedAfterSomeDate
    = archive.GetEntries(0, int.MaxValue).Where(entry => entry.ArchiveDate > someDate).ToList();
```

Remember that the `ArchiveEntry.ArchiveDate` property uses `UTC` time so you may want to use `ArchiveEntry.ArchiveLocalDate` instead.

You can turn off/on `Recycle bin` in **Sitecore** config file:

```xml
  <!--  RECYCLE BIN
        If true, when deleting items in the client, they will
        be moved to the recycle bin rather than being deleted
        Default value: true
  -->
  <setting name="RecycleBinActive" value="true" />
```

Comment: And for how long are these kept in recycle bin?

Comment: From what I know there is no time limit. You can see archived items using `Recycle Bin` application from Sitecore Desktop.

Comment: Another question about this and i think i am done. Is there a way of selecting a deleted item by its template?

Comment: Unfortunately `ArchiveEntry` class is limited comparing to `Item` class. You cannot get template of the item but you can get location of the item before it was removed (`ArchiveEntry.OriginalLocation`), `ItemId`, `ParentId` and `Name`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also retrieve a list of Items from the History table, using the `HistoryEngine` API:

```
var db = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master");
var historyEngine = new Sitecore.Data.Engines.HistoryEngine(db);
var deletedItems = historyEngine.GetHistory(fromDateUTC, toDateUTC)
                                .Where(history => history.Action == HistoryAction.Deleted);
```

Note that by default only 30 days worth of information is stored. You can increase this in config:

```
<Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
  <obj type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)HistoryStorage, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param connectionStringName="$(id)"/>
    <EntryLifeTime>30.00:00:00</EntryLifeTime>
  </obj>
</Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
```